# Pagination is not user friendly using php

Tags: php

Can someone help me why my '<<' not be in a box. And anyone know how to fix the coding as if i have 20 pages it will be page 1 until 20. I want it to be like ----->  eg: 1 2 3 4 5 ....17 . something like this.

```
   $record_per_page = 10;
  $page = '';
    if(isset($_GET["page"]))
  {
    $page = $_GET["page"];
  }
    else
  {
    $page = 1;
  }

  $start_from = ($page-1)*$record_per_page;

  $sql = "SELECT id, created, fullname, level, filename, status FROM borang ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $record_per_page"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 }
```

-----here have another coding to fetch the data from database

```
 <?php
$page_result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($page_result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_records/$record_per_page);
?>
<ul class="pagination">
      <?php if ($page==1) { ?>
        <li class="disabled"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></li>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href=permohonanA.php?page=<?php echo $page-1 ?>" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
       <?php
      for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)
        if ($i == $page)
          echo "<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"permohonanA.php?page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
        else
          echo "<li><a href=\"permohonanA.php?page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
      ?>
      <?php if ($page==$total_pages) { ?>
        <li class="disabled"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></li>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href=permohonanA.php?page=<?php echo $page+1 ?>" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: And the question is...?  What does this code do (or does not do) that you do not like?  What does this code generate (view source in the browser) that you want to do differently?

Comment: Also check your syntax for your `<a>` anchors, your `"` double-quotes are all wrong (the ones right after `<li>` tags).

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable with server side configuration.
Sorry it is a bit off topic.
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html